# CPU and/or RAM productivity when working with big integers

Tags: c#, cpu

yesterday I was solving one exam problem, when found something very interesting (at least for me). The program is for factorials (very big ones) and the result is how much zeroes there are on the end of the number (in some cases `2500` zeros..). So I did what I could, but found that when enter number like `100 000` it takes exactly `1;30 - 1;33min` to output the result. I thought its because of my CPU (it is not very fast). I've sent the .exe to some of my friends to try it because they have very good PCs when we are talking about performance - exactly the same result (`1;33min`).

My question is why is the time to solve the task the same. *I know there are better ways to write my core so it wouldn't take so long*, but this is very important for me to understand as a beginner programmer.
So here is my code:

```
static void Main()
        {
            int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()),
                zeroCounter = 0;
            BigInteger fact = 1;
            var startTime = DateTime.Now;

            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            {
                fact *= i;
                Console.Write("\r{0}", DateTime.Now - startTime);
            }
            BigInteger factTarget = fact;
            while (factTarget % 10 == 0)
            {
                factTarget /= 10;
                zeroCounter++;
                Console.Write("\r{0}", DateTime.Now - startTime);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Result is number with {0} zeros.", zeroCounter);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Finished for: {0}", DateTime.Now - startTime);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\nPres any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

I am very sorry If this is the wrong place to ask, I did my best to find what I was looking for before I post this.

Comment: Your code is emitting a line to the console at every iteration of the loops. The computation time will be a small fraction of the time to execute an iteration as the system calls required to output a line will be very slow by comparison. I/O processes are not generally not bound by processor speed but by other factors so most PCs will execute the program in much the same time. Try the experiment again with output only before and after the computation loops.

Comment: exacly as @Hobo Sapiens has written- additionally you may want to use StopWatch class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  to measure the time as it measures only the time needed for your code to execute.

Comment: I agree with @PiotrPiotr's recommendation to use `Stopwatch`. That said, `Stopwatch` measures elapsed time essentially as recording `DateTime.Now` would. The big difference is that a) `Stopwatch` can be more precise (depending on the PC), and b) it is not subject to variations that might be caused e.g. by resetting the PC's clock (which on most PCs happens automatically and periodically), or by changes in timezones (when using `Utc` instead of `UtcNow`). The odds of either of those happening during this test are low, but it's still a good suggestion.

Comment: Great help with this StopWach! Thank you .
And about the I/O without the WriteLines - yes you are right @HoboSapiens now the time is  00:01:23.5856140 .

Comment: You're executing this on a single core. Even if your friends have 8 cores juiced up in their PC, you're still bounding the computational operation to a single one. Thus, you're seeing nearly identical results across different PCs.

Comment: Ok @YuvalItzchakov but is there a way to make it use all the cores, so we can be able to see the difference between the processors?

Comment: Of course. Look into the `Parallel` class. Specifically [`Parallel.For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  What you'll want to do is partition the work into sub groups, and then merge them once they all complete.

Comment: 1) You're creating new 150kB array on each iteration of the loop. 2) Without the `Console.WriteLine` calls it takes 56 seconds on my computer using a 32 bit program and 37 seconds using a 64 bit program.

Comment: Replace the second `while` with zeroCounter = factTarget.ToString().Reverse().TakeWhile( x => x == '0' ).Count();

Answer (score 5):

The thing that I notice immediately about your code is that you have included `Console.WriteLine()` statements in your computational loops.

The fact is, I/O is *much* slower for a computer to handle than computations, even under ideal conditions. And I wouldn't say that the Windows console window is a particularly efficient implementation of that particular kind of I/O. Furthermore, I/O tends to be less dependent on CPU and memory differences from machine to machine.

In other words, it seems very likely to me that you are primarily measuring I/O throughput and not computational throughput, and so it's not surprising to see consistent results between machines.

For what it's worth, when I run your example on my laptop, if I disable the output I can complete the computation in about a minute. I get something closer to your 1:30 time if I use the code as-is.

**EDIT:**
I recommend the answer from Hans Passant as well. Memory I/O is still I/O and is, as I describe above, much less variable from machine to machine than CPU speed. It's my hope that the above general-purpose description gives ideas for where the difference could be (without access to each of the machines in question, there's not really any way to know *for sure* what is the cause), but Hans's answer provides some very good detail about the memory I/O issue in particular and is very much worth reading.

Comment: I've tried without WriteLines and the result is `Finished for: 00:01:23.5856140` so - yes you were right. But even the time to perform all the operations is the same for diferent PC's which ramains mistery for me. :D

Answer (score 3):

> now the time is 00:01:23.5856140

The speed of this program is determined by the bandwidth of the RAM in your machine.  It is a design-constant and unrelated to the speed of the processor.  RAM plays a role here because of the very large number of digits in the factorial, they don't fit the CPU caches anymore.  And the memory access pattern for a  BigInteger multiplication is very unfriendly, all digits are required to multiply a number.

Your program takes 57 seconds on my laptop, I know it has PC3-12800 RAM.  Which has a peak transfer rate of 12800 MB/sec, give or take the CAS latency (I don't know mine).  So we can calculate the RAM speed on your and your friend's machine:

> 1:23 = 83 sec, 57/83 x 12800 = 8790 MB/sec.

Which is a [pretty close match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#Modules) for PC3-8500.  A run-of-the-mill RAM speed very common in white-box machines, the kind you'd get from a vendor like Dell.  Your friend's fast PC is a bit of a toaster, break it to him gently :)

---

Fwiw, why the highly upvoted post doesn't have much of an affect on the speed can use an explanation as well.  The console window that your program uses is owned by another process.  Conhost.exe, you can see it back in the Processes tab of Taskman.exe.  It takes care of scrolling and painting the window, under the hood your program uses process-interop to tell it to update the window.

This happens *while* your program is running, on another thread, so your program is only bogged-down when it firehoses Conhost.exe, sending updates faster than it can handle.  So, at the start of your program you are still fast and will get bogged down.  But not when the number of digits starts to grow large and your multiplications start to get slow.  Overall, the slowdown is not that great.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the core or the processor the pc has a fixed size of internal buses, that store the data. The speed of RAM is 10-1000 times slower than Processor. There also something called Cache memory, but the size of cache memory is dam small. So Whats so large size of RAM you have in your pc, it will be still slow and take time. Coz when it reaches High Numbers, the numbers take time to Read and Write to and from Memory.

Plus writing each time to the screen eats up some time.